# Content security policy - Angular js application (Style-src, script-src - without 'unsafe-eval', 'unsafe-inline')

Tags: angularjs, unsafe-inline, content-security-policy

if someone can help me whether we can add Content security policy style-src, script-src without 'unsafe-inline' to angular js applications. I tried to apply CSP, but it is throwing error for the js libraries.

It tried ng-csp in angular js, it is not working. And i avoided using inline styles, but its throwing error for libraries (example: Jquery library throwing error)